# How to negate custom wndow.onscroll function in dialog, reverting to normal behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using the function below to cheaply disable scrolling during a jqueryui.dialog().  However, after the dialog is closed, how do I reverse this back to normal scrolling behaviour?

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

Comment: are you trying to just make it so that the main window doesnt scroll if the user scrolls something within the dialog?

Comment: Yes. Currently, if their cursor is over the, ahem, overlay, it scrolls the main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the onscroll event you can just use css overflow:hidden to remove the scroll of the window and then overflow:initial to set it back to normal

```
//Before displaying your dialog
jQuery('html').css({overflow:"hidden"});

//After closing the dialog
jQuery('html').css({overflow:"initial"});
```

If you want to stick to using the onscroll event, simply save a reference to the current onscoll and then set it back when done

```
var scrollRef;

//Before displaying your dialog
scrollRef = window.onscroll;
window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0); };

//After closing your dialog
window.onscroll = scrollRef;
```

Comment: Accepted since it's stamped first, although it shows at the bottom.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Save the old function somewhere. For example:

```
var old_onscroll;

function replace() {
  old_onscroll = window.onscroll;
  window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0); };
}

function restore() {
  window.onscroll = old_onscroll;
}
```